# many COM objects in one project

Tags: c#, winforms, com

I'm writing a program in C # WinForms and I have a problem. In the project, I use two COM objects to handle external devices (scanners). At the compilation stage, I have both objects and the program does not return any errors. However, when I share the program with other users who do not have these objects registered in the system, the application simply does not start. It looks as if the program is looking for drivers in the system immediately after launching the exe file. I tried to stop with breakpoints in the main class (where the program starts) but the application stops earlier. How should I solve this to let the application run at least (it is known that it will not supporting the scanner).

Comment: When you rely on somebody else's library then you always have a requirement that it is available on the user's machine.  If the vendor's installer can't solve this problem then talk to them to find out how to properly deploy it yourself.  If your program is supposed to limp along anyway then use try/catch in your code to discover that it is unusable.  Test that by uninstalling the library on your dev machine.

Comment: Solve it by registering the COM dlls on the target machines with your installer.

Comment: Use late binding instead? [Load a COM dll at runtime?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3611829)